# Do event receivers have a file handling limit?

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, performance

I created an event receiver inheriting from SPItemEventReceiver for document libraries that moves files to specific folders and changes some metadata columns that I've added to them.

I created a separate application to update numerous files in a smaller period of time I noticed performance issues.

Ofcourse I looked into some good code practices while writing event receivers on msdn, but a question remains:

Do event receivers have a file ammount to be safely handled in a certain ammount of time? 
Is there a way to tell what is the safest ammount of files to handle "once"?

Comment: I think that for this purpose the timer job will be better.

Comment: Have you ran performance monitors whilst uploading documents, see if the number of threads is flatlining when you experience performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think, there isn't any file handling limit however I believe it depends or effects CPU usage. We have event receivers on document libraries that are used by hundred of clients in a specific amount of time.

So in short, There isn't any "Known" limit however if a large number of events occur but your CPU/RAM isn't capable of handling processes then your SharePoint will most likely crash.

I never done it myself but you can use Visual Studio to test performance of your SharePoint portal or possibly event receivers.

[Testing Performance and Stress Using Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540.aspx)